# on alert script working and without it not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

If some body can answer.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    //alert("Before..");
    $('#myGallery').galleryView({
        panel_width: 960,
        panel_height: 424,
        frame_width: 160,
        frame_height: 70,
        panel_scale: "nocrop",
        frame_opacity: 0.6,
        pause_on_hover: true
    });
    //alert("AFter....");    

    $('#homeGallery').innerfade({
            speed:900,
            timeout: 8000 
    });

});
</script>
```

above is the code it is not working
if I remove the alert("before.") it will work.

Comment: Any errors in the javascript console? (shift-ctrl-J in firefox/chrome).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be an issue with some required parts of the document not having been loaded yet. After you have dismissed the dialog, they have and the code works.

Have you tried using [`document.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event) instead of [`document.ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)?

Comment: This helped me. I used $(window).load and it worked. But the problem is it is taking too much time in loading means on live images with size in mbz. so it is not possible for us to use that. And even settimeout is not working so can anyone give me some another solution

Answer (score 0):

I have run into similar issues before and it always suggests a race condition. Although you should be fine because you have a `document.ready`... to test this, try putting that call into a `setTimeout( function(), 1000)` and let me know what happens

Answer (score 0):

Can you trying clearing your browser cache. If that doesn't work can you provide the HTML schema